# Transform table using Cross Apply

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table in this format.

```
+----------+-------+---------+--------+--------+
| TicketId | PubId | PubName | Model1 | Model2 |
+----------+-------+---------+--------+--------+
|     1234 |    12 | abc     | xyz1   | pqr1   |
|     1235 |    34 | iuy     | fgy6   | piu8   |
+----------+-------+---------+--------+--------+
```

and I am targeting to create a table like the one given below.

```
+----------+---------+-------+
| TicketId | Display | Value |
+----------+---------+-------+
|     1234 | PubId   | 12    |
|     1234 | PubName | abc   |
|     1234 | Model1  | xyz1  |
|     1234 | Model2  | pqr1  |
|     1235 | PubId   | 34    |
|     1235 | PubName | iuy   |
|     1235 | Model1  | fgy61 |
|     1235 | Model2  | piu8  |
+----------+---------+-------+
```

I know I can do `CROSS APPLY` but I am not be to do it because of complexity. 
Can someone help me with this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do :

```
select t.TicketId, tt.Display, tt.Value
from table t cross apply
     ( values ('PubId', PubId), ('PubName', PubName), ('Model1', Model1), ('Model2', Model2) 
     ) tt(Display, Value)
order by t.TicketId;
```